# Regex to search fontawesome icon name

Tags: javascript, regex

Need regex to search font awesome icon name from string.

What i tried so far:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'; 
    var res = str.match(/'fa-'*/);
    return res;
}
```

My function should return "fa-edit" as icon name

What should be my regex to find name ??

Comment: What tool/language are you planning to use?  Do you plan to run the regex from within your IDE?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what tool/language you are using for the regex, but here is general solution which should work in most places:

```
<i class="(?:.*\s)?([^"]*)"><\/i>
```

The last class inside the `<i>` tag should appear as the first capture group.

### Demo

```js
var str = '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'; 
var res = str.match(/<i class="(?:.*\s)?([^"]*)"><\/i>/);
console.log(res[1])
```

Code snippet taken from @mike_t

Answer (score 2):

If i correctly assume you are using javascript, try this:

*Note: i also added as leading characters space and single/double quote, in case the class is specified as ie. "fa-edit fa" or 'fa-edit fa'*

```js
var str = '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'; 
    var res = str.match(/.*[\ \"\']+(fa-[a-zA-z0-9]*).*/);
    console.log(res[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

Although regex seems like a fantastic idea, it can run into issues: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Yes, I know, if it's a known subset regex can be used; but it doesn't mean it should.

This answer provides a way of converting the string to a DOM element, obtaining the classes and parsing them for a class beginning with `fa-`

---

### Code

```js
var str = '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>',
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");

var x = doc.firstChild.className
          .split(" ")
          .filter(String)
          .filter(function(e) {
            return e.startsWith("fa-");
          });

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will do what the title asks for - find fontawesome icon names.

```
fa-[a-zA-Z0-9-]+
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/zPuxg0/3

Note that it will also include modifiers such as `fa-2x`, `fa-spin` etc. So be sure to filter those out depending on your needs.